# rename file to match the file in second folder with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am working on renaming a file from folder 1 to the same name as the file in folder 2 but I need to retain the extension of the file from folder 1.

In the resource from Stackoverflow, I found a person that posted a nearly exact question except that i need to retain my extension from the file in folder 1.

Here was the sample code I worked with found at StackOverflow:

```
$names = @()
$getPath = "C:\Temp\get"
$setPath = "C:\Temp\set"
Get-ChildItem $getPath |
    Foreach-object {
        $names += $_
    }
$i = 0
Get-ChildItem $setPath |
    Foreach-object {
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $names[$i]
        $i++ 
    }
```

Comment: It seems you have already discovered the `.fullname` property of files, there is also a `.extension` property that grabs the extension.

Comment: I have tried but I seem to be missing the puzzle. everything works ok but the file that is renamed in the set also has the extension from the Get folder. I have tried to add the extension property but it does not respond. I will keep plugging at it. Please post if you any direction for me. thank you.

Comment: Try `Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $names[$i].$($_.extension)`

Comment: I get the following when your suggestion is added Error: Rename-Item : cannot bind argument to parameter "NewName' because it is null.

Comment: Oops, it is trying to read the extension as a property, try escaping the `.` like ```Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $names[$i]`.$($_.extension)```

Comment: error at line: 27 char:51  `.$($_.extension)

Comment: `Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$names[$i].$($_.extension)"`

Comment: Your suggestion provided me a close enough result to work it out. Ultimately removing the dot before the variable sign performed the result to which i was seeking. Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$names[$i]$($_.extension)". Thank you very much for your time and guidance to get me pointed in the right direction.